# .htaccess with redirection won't work

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have enable mod_rewrite in my linuxmint 15. But .htaccess wont work. Here is my apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/xampp/htdocs
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/xampp/htdocs/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Pleas help me. ask me if you need any info.

also here is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mehedi.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and the htaccess file is located in "/var/www/xampp/htdocs/" directory.

Thank you

Comment: That should redirect everything to `mehedi.php` unless the file or folder exists. what's the issue/error?

Answer (score 0):

Anything useful in your apache error log? I would recommend checking your httpd.conf for any Options directives that are being set. It's possible that your Options for AllowOverride are set to None or something other than "All" for that directory or directories above that DocumentRoot you have configured. Hope this helps --Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate the rewrite module? (`sudo a2enmod rewrite` + `sudo service apache2 restart`)